# cordova.advanced.http post request is not working

Tags: android, html, node.js, api, cordova

I am trying to hook up my backend to a cordova application and I am in the early stages of development so I just trying to test it in the browser. I cannot get the post request to work, or and api call for the fact, my url(I changed it for the post) is correct because I can hit it through postman and its running on a external server, I am using the cordova plugin: cordova-advanced-http

```
const button = document.getElementById('loginButton');

button.addEventListener('click', login);
function login() {
    const options = {
        method: 'post',
        data: { email: "mud@water.sand", password: "P@ssw0rd"},
        headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer Token: token' }
    };
    console.log(options);
    cordova.plugin.http.sendRequest('http://oa.com:8080/user/login/', options, function(response) {
        // prints 200
        console.log(response.status);
        console.log(response.data.token);
    }, function(response) {
        // prints 403
        console.log(response.status);
        //prints Permission denied
        console.log(response.error);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, in my html I was executing my script on a submit while in my script I had it defined to execute on a button